# is email received from "mailer daemon@report domain submitter esa1.hc3329-29.iphmx" a DMARC report?

Tags: dmarc

received email from "mailer daemon@report domain submitter esa1.hc3329-29.iphmx" which appears to have an dmarc report xml file attached, is it a legit dmarc report ?  if not correct to ask this question here please make suggestion where to find answer ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know  iphmx.com domain belongs to [Cisco IronPort](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/about/corporate-strategy-office/acquisitions/ironport.html). You can perform IP address lookup for esa8.sap.c3s2.iphmx.com 
https://network-tools.webwiz.net/ip-information.htm

[image: IP Address Information for esa8.sap.c3s2.iphmx.com]

...and yes, DMARC XML reports coming from Reporter, which name ends with iphmx.com, are legitimate reports, I receive a lot of them

[image]

Comment: Thanks,  I don't understand why the Dmarc report would have "mailer daemon" at the beginning of the email address ?

Comment: [DMARC RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7489#appendix-C) does not explain exactly the purpose of email address to be specified in **email** tag.  
The other [DMARC related draft document](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-crocker-dmarc-bcp-03#section-7.1) says about *email* tag -
"_The email address where a report recipient can alert the report generator to problems related to the DMARC aggregate report.  This can be a mailing list address or contain multiple email addresses._"

Comment: Looking on DMARC XML reports I receive, I see that many XML feeders use "no-reply" (e.g. Google, Yahoo) or "mailer-daemon" addresses, and replies to that addresses are bouncing in most cases. 

So, apparently most of DMARC aggregate report feeders send reports from not-existing email address (obviously, to avoid floods)